# Matching/finding rows in different sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have 2 sheets with columns like merchant, amount, data, etc. The thing 100% common between the two sheets is the amount. I want to match/find out the rows from sheet 1 + sheet 2 that contain the same amount. In one of the sheets I have more data than in the other, so for example, 3rd row from sheet 1 does not match with 3rd row from sheet 2. Somehow I have to search after the amount.

Comment: So, which worksheet has most? Or does that differ? Can the amount occur multiple times? How do you want the results to be displayed? Your question leaves out a lot of detail :( Please [edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/787398/edit) and make it clearer, it will help us to understand :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it but your question is very unclear :(

```
Sub FindTheThings()

Dim resultRow As Integer
resultRow = 2

Dim currentRow As Integer
currentRow = 2

Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Value = "Sheet1 row"
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B1").Value = "Sheet2 row"

Do While (Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & currentRow).Value <> "")

Dim amount As String
amount = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & currentRow).Value

Dim currentRowSheet2 As String
currentRowSheet2 = 2

    Do While (Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & currentRowSheet2).Value <> "")

        Dim sheet2amount As String
        sheet2amount = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & currentRowSheet2).Value

        If (sheet2amount = amount) Then

            Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & resultRow).Value = currentRow
            Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B" & resultRow).Value = currentRowSheet2

            resultRow = resultRow + 1
            Exit Do
        End If

    currentRowSheet2 = currentRowSheet2 + 1
    Loop
currentRow = currentRow + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

There are faults, such as what happens if there are multiple occurances of the amount, what happens if sheet1 data has more or less values than sheet2, how the information is to be presented etc

Regardless this VBa should get you going as it can be tweaked

Sheet 1

[image]

Sheet 2

[image]

Sheet 3 (created after macro run)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

`=VLOOKUP(B1,Sheet1!$A$1:$B$28,2,0)` finds the first instance.

`=COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet2!B2)` tells if there is more than on instance.